# what's wrong here?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

i used this code to replace the first " with `` and the second one with '' 
everything works just fine except it runs through the loop one more time after the last character is read and that makes the program print another character

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
void main ()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("infile.txt");
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("outfile.txt");
    char c ;

    int i = 0 ;
    while ( !infile.eof() )
    { 
        infile.get(c)
            if (c=='\"')
            {
                i++ ;
                if (i%2==0)
                    outfile<<"\'\'";
                else 
                    outfile<<"``";
            }
            else 
                outfile<<c;
    }
    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: `infile.eof()` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  This has to be a duplicate, right?

Comment: To help the above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong. On another note, http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: @chris - thanks for finding the dupe.

Comment: @CarlNorum, It's hardly finding. I had it bookmarked :p

Comment: You're not even checking the result of the files opening. If they don't exist you get errors, but still try to operate on them

Comment: You forgot to write a decent question title, to search, to read your C++ book, and to give your `main` a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `while ( !infile.eof() )` - this only checks if the previous read hit the end of the file, not if the next one will. So when the last character is read, it loops round again, sees that it hasn't hit the end of file yet and then proceeds to read another character even though there isn't another character to read. Your `c` will have the same value from the previous iteration.

Instead, do this:

```
while (infile.get(c))
{
  // ... 
}
```

This will read a character from the file and then, if that was succesful, will do something with that character.

Comment: The reason this works isn't obvious by reading the documentation for [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). I figured it out, but it might be worth including an explanation.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The problem there is the phrase "_the_ documentation". One should read a proper C++ book to gain an understanding of the language that _cannot_ be garnered from an API reference.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel, I can't fault your suggestion at all. It's still useful to have that kind of information here on StackOverflow though.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I can't disagree with that at all. :)